# How to pull posts into two columns with different image sizes using $counter variable?

Tags: query, columns

I have a custom module pulling one specific category with 6 posts displaying the featured image into 2 columns. I like the first article of the top of each column to display a large image as shown in the image below:
[image: Module]

To mention that I have the necessary CSS code for the first and second column but do not know how to properly use the $counter variable to be able to correctly display this module.

```
<?php

$td_query = new WP_Query( $td_args );

$counter = 1;

if ( $td_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $td_query->have_posts() ) {

        $td_query->the_post();

        if ( $counter == 1 ) {

            $output .= '<div class="left-col">'; // first column
            $output .= '<div class="big-image">';
            $output .= the_post_thumbnail( 'big' ); // 1 big image
            $output .= '</div>';

        } elseif ( $counter == 2 ) {

            $output .= '<div class="small-images">';    
            $output .= the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); // 2 small images
            $output .= '</div>';

            $output .= '</div>';

        } elseif ( $counter == 4 ) { 

            $output .= '<div class="right-col">'; // right column
            $output .= '<div class="big-image">'
            $output .= the_post_thumbnail( 'big' ); // 1 big image
            $output .= '</div>';

        } else {

            $output .= '<div class="small-images">';    
            $output .= the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); // 2 small images
            $output .= '</div>';

            $output .= '</div>';

        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
wp_reset_query();

return $buffer;
```

What I'm doing wrong in the code above (simplified & pseudo code) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to simplify it. **IF** We're in this loop we're either going to have both a left **AND** right column **OR** at least a left column, if we have less than 4 posts, so we can move a container div outside the main conditional:

```
if ( $td_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $td_query->have_posts() ) {

        $td_query->the_post();

        if ( $counter == 1 || $counter == 4 ) {

            $output .= ( $counter == 1 ) ? '<div class="left-col">' : '</div><div class="right-col">';
            $output .= '<div class="big-image">';
            $output .= the_post_thumbnail( 'big' ); // 1 big image
            $output .= '</div>';

        } else {

            $output .= '<div class="small-images">';    
            $output .= the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); // 2 small images
            $output .= '</div>';

        }
        $counter++;
    }

    $output .= '</div>'; 
}
```

Skimming over your original code it looks like that should work for you so I'm not exactly sure what problems your currently having with it. Either way hopefully the above works for you!

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that in both codes (mine and yours) the small images are outside the left & right col divs.

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer, the change is that **IF** there's a `right-col`, then we can close the `left-col` div, otherwise at the end of the loop, always close whichever col is currently open.